# How to use a jSON string with formfield name and formfield value to populate form fields jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following jSON string:

```
[{"meta_key":"algemeen_reden","meta_value":"oplevering"},{"meta_key":"algemeen_netspanning","meta_value":"230"}]
```

Now I use the following script to populate form fields:

```
// Call Algemeen Data
get_algemeen_data = function (checklist_id)
{
    $.getJSON(MAP_URL+'onderhoud/handle/fetch_data.php?cat=get_algemeen_e&checklist_id='+ checklist_id, function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {
            $.each(value, function(vars, values)
            {
                console.log(vars + " = " + values);
                if(vars == "noodverlichting" && values == "1")
                {
                    $('#collapseNoodverlichting').collapse({show: true});
                    $('.togglerNoodverlichting span:first').removeClass("badge-success").addClass("badge-danger");
                    $('.togglerNoodverlichting span').eq(1).removeClass("oi-plus").addClass("oi-minus");
                    $('#noodverlichting').val("1");
                }

                $('input[type="text"][name="' + vars + '"]').val(values);
                $('textarea[name="' + vars + '"]').val(values);
                $('select[name="' + vars + '"]').val(values);
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + vars + '"]:checked').prop( "checked", false );
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + vars + '"][value="' + values + '"]').prop( "checked", true );
            })
        });
    })
    // using the fail promise callback
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
}
get_algemeen_data(checklist_id);
// End Call Algemeen Data
```

Problem is, I get the following response:

```
meta_key = algemeen_reden
meta_value = oplevering
meta_key = algemeen_netspanning
meta_value = 230
```

I want the response to be:

```
algemeen_reden = oplevering
algemeen_netspanning = 230
```

I know my codes can be shorter and prettier, but that's not the issue right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the second loop,use the dot notation to read the object:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value)
{
  console.log(value.meta_key+' = '+value.meta_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a json of key/value pairs that you want condensed into an associative array, it can work as follows:

```
json = '[{"meta_key":"algemeen_reden","meta_value":"oplevering"},{"meta_key":"algemeen_netspanning","meta_value":"230"}]';
data = JSON.parse(json);
values=[];
for (i in data) values[data[i].meta_key]=data[i].meta_value;
```

Now values[] contains:

```
algemeen_netspanning:"230"
algemeen_reden:"oplevering"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you al so much!

I have the following sollution:

```
// Call Algemeen Data
get_algemeen_data = function (checklist_id)
{
    $.getJSON(MAP_URL+'onderhoud/handle/fetch_data.php?cat=get_algemeen_e&checklist_id='+ checklist_id, function(data) 
    {
        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {
            console.log(data[key].meta_key + " = " + data[key].meta_value);
                if(data[key].meta_key == "noodverlichting" && data[key].meta_value == "1")
                {
                    $('#collapseNoodverlichting').collapse({show: true});
                    $('.togglerNoodverlichting span:first').removeClass("badge-success").addClass("badge-danger");
                    $('.togglerNoodverlichting span').eq(1).removeClass("oi-plus").addClass("oi-minus");
                    $('#noodverlichting').val("1");
                }

                $('input[type="text"][name="' + data[key].meta_key + '"]').val(data[key].meta_value);
                $('textarea[name="' + data[key].meta_key + '"]').val(data[key].meta_value);
                $('select[name="' + data[key].meta_key + '"]').val(data[key].meta_value);
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + data[key].meta_key + '"]:checked').prop( "checked", false );
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="' + data[key].meta_key + '"][value="' + data[key].meta_value + '"]').prop( "checked", true );
        });
    })
    // using the fail promise callback
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
}
get_algemeen_data(checklist_id);
// End Call Algemeen Data
```